# Force closing app and ActivityNotFoundException while using ListActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am following an youtube tutorial to create android apps.
In one of the tutorials they told how to create a Menu class using List activity.

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

String classes[] = {"Start","example1","example2","example3","example4","example5","example6"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try{
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.add." + cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And add activity in the manifest.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:exported="false"
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:exported="false"
        android:name="com.example.add.Start"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.add.START" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My project has a Start class which adds one to a counter and display it,
a Splash class which defines background image, music and it is the main class.
Before adding Menu class my app worked fine,but after i added it my app began to force close and logcat showed an ActivityNotFoundException and error in Splash class at line 28

```
public class Splash extends Activity{

MediaPlayer ourSong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle Dab) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(Dab);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.nodebeat);
    ourSong.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){   //framework to start a new thread
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStart = new Intent("com.example.add.MENU");
                startActivity(openStart);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
}
```

So please help i am new to android app development and im struck here.
Links to the Logcat logs:-
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxLaXhL-q50-MHlhUW93SmxNT0U/edit Debug Log
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxLaXhL-q50-b1pzbVpIcVNQR2s/edit Error Log

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong intent filter for what you're trying to launch. So either change

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />
```

to

```
 <action android:name="com.example.add.MENU" />
```

So that everything matches.

**Or** change your call in your code so it is:

```
Intent openStart = new Intent("android.intent.action.MENU");
```

You should read about [Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

You could also use the explict intent, since you're not exporting this Activity and you know its name, I don't see a need for an intent filter.

```
Intent openStart = new Intent(Splash.this, Menu.class);
startActivity(openStart);
```

Comment: But in the tutorials those methods just worked fine,so how am i supposed to get errors.

Comment: You're welcome! And as for the tutorial working properly, there's always the chance you mistyped or that the tutorial doesn't exactly work. Always check the comments - usually people complain if it doesn't work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Intent action in below both(1 and 2) places should be same , which are not. make them identical.

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />// (1)

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

and

```
 Intent openStart = new Intent("com.example.add.MENU"); (2)
```